# Dynamically change caching of pages

Tags: django

I want to cache a page dynamically

Generally we have:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Or

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/<int:code>/', cache_page(60 * 15)(my_view)),
]
```

But inside the view I want to judge based on some logic, change the cache mechanism (like clear the cache and again start new cache)

```
def my_view(request):
   if some logic is true:
      then clear cache_page()

      execute the view login
      response = ......

      add response to cache_page()
      return response

   else:
      return the old cached page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of digging into the source code i found how to show cache pages if data is not updated else show the modified data view

dont use cache_page in url.py

```
from django.middleware.cache import CacheMiddleware

@login_required

someview(request, slug=None)

    ######  data_updated
    # Check the conditions data modified is updated or not
    data_updated = True/False
    ######

    cachemiddleware = CacheMiddleware(cache_timeout=60*15)

    if data_updated:

        #######
            # RUN all the code for view
            # response = ..........
        #######


        # this is required because if the url is already cached it will be false
        request._cache_update_cache = True

        return cachemiddleware.process_response(request, response)

    else:

        result = cachemiddleware.process_request(request)

        if result is not None:
            return result
        else:

            #######
            # RUN all the code for view
            # response = ..........
            #######

            return cachemiddleware.process_response(request, response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your use case the `Conditional View Processing` would be best fit, It does what you are looking for except it relies on `Etag` header to tell the browser that the content hasn't been changed. More about `Conditional view processing` at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/conditional-view-processing/

Comment: I hope this is more for session based thing. Assuming i open the page on firefox after deleting its cache and history, then there is no more http headers available for the first time to the browser and the view has to run. But if i have a cache, then irrespective of session if the page is already cached it shows back very quickly without the need to go through the view function.

Comment: You are right, then you may want to write a custom middleware and check the condition there before the request hits your view, if the condition is not met then just clear the cache.